# Crosstab query error | Ms Access does not Recognized MEMBER_ID as a Valid filed or expression

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

This has been a nightmare.

I created this Crosstab Query in MS Access 2007; the query works perfectly when run alone, however when I add the query to other tables; example: when I join the query to other tables which are part of other queries I get this error:

```
Ms Access does not Recognized MEMBER_ID as a Valid filed or expression.
```

I have search every where but cannot find anything specifically to my issue or scenario.

If I run the query alone it works.

Here is the code:

```
TRANSFORM First(MEMBER_PHONE.PHONE_NBR) AS FirstOfPhone_NBR
SELECT MEMBER_PHONE.[MEMBER_ID]
FROM MEMBER_PHONE
WHERE (((MEMBER_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE) In ("CELL","HOME","WORK")))
GROUP BY MEMBER_PHONE.[MEMBER_ID]
PIVOT MEMBER_PHONE.[PHONE_TYPE];
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work if you take another approach to the cross tab query. If you don't use the wizards in Access, and built the query in standard (Access) SQL, it would look something like this

```
SELECT 
    MEMBER_ID,
    FIRST(IIF(MEMBER_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE = "CELL",MEMBER_PHONE.PHONE_NBR,"")) As [CELL],
    FIRST(IIF(MEMBER_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE = "HOME",MEMBER_PHONE.PHONE_NBR,"")) As [HOME],
    FIRST(IIF(MEMBER_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE = "WORK",MEMBER_PHONE.PHONE_NBR,"")) As [WORK]
FROM
    MEMBER_PHONE
WHERE 
    MEMBER_PHONE.PHONE_TYPE In ("CELL","HOME","WORK") 
GROUP BY
    MEMBER_ID
```

You should then be able to link to other tables/queries on MEMBER_ID.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort; I am getting an error message about wrong number of arguments. Not sure why that is, but the error is referring to the IIF statement.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy Edited my answer - had an extra paren in there.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works as needed. Have a great day!